# Dynamically add textbox(s) in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code-

```
    <div class="service_box">
       <div class="form">
           <form class="cmxform">
               <label>EL POS :</label>
               <input type="checkbox">
                <!-----------------------
                 multiple textboxes shall be added here as
                 <input type="text" class="someclass"> ---> textbox 1
                 <input type="text" class="someclass"> ---> textbox 2
                 ------------------------>
               <button id="add">Add</button>
           </form>
       </div>
   </div>
```

I would like to add textbox(s) on the add button click event in jquery. Any help?

Comment: have you tried something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will enable you to both add text boxes **and remove them**, just in case you change your mind:

```
$(function() {
    $('#add').on('click', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('<div/>').addClass( 'new-text-div' )
        .html( $('<input type="textbox"/>').addClass( 'someclass' ) )
        .append( $('<button/>').addClass( 'remove' ).text( 'Remove' ) )
        .insertBefore( this );
    });
    $(document).on('click', 'button.remove', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest( 'div.new-text-div' ).remove();
    });
});
```

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/dqydM/)

Comment: your solution works well. But Dynamically added textboxes are not taking any input like a read-only textbox. Would you please suggest me further?

Comment: Sure, we can work on that. What do you mean "no taking any input ..."?

Comment: It behaves like a read-only textbox. Its taking neither focus nor input. I tried the following code, then it worked. 

            $(document).on('click', '.ElMsisdn', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
               // $('#sample').attr('readonly', 'true');
                $(this).focus();
            });

However, my above code is not a fair solution. Please suggest.

Comment: Which browser and version are you using? I have tested my demo in FF 32, Chrome 37 and IE 11 and the text inputs work fine. They accept focus by clicking and via pressing the tab key on the keyboard. Are you able to create a demo showing the issue?

Comment: I can send you the real link. But i am not going to show that url publicly. How can i send that link personally?

Comment: You did not give browser version and os. My profile should show how to reach me.

Answer (score 1):

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2sL7f/4/)**

```
$('.cmxform').append('<br/><input type="text" class="someclass"> ');
```

Use **[append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** function to append an element dynamically to an element in the DOM.

Other options:

1. **[appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)**
2. **[prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)**

Depends where and how you wish to append the elements.

Comment: I want it above the add button.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with jquery like this:

```
    $("#add").click(function(event){

     event.preventDefault();

     $("input.someclass:first").clone(true).val("").appendTo(".cmxform");

    });
```

`clone()` will create copy of textbox after that reset it's value using `val("")` and then append it to form using `appendto()`

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tq7yK/)

Answer (score 0):

```
        I have used something like this. It may be helpful

        HTML :

        <div class="filter_selector">
            <input type="text">
            <button class="remove_filter_category">-</button>
            <button class="add_filter_category">+</button>

        </div>

    jquery:

    $(document).ready(function() {

        function updateFilterUI(){
          $('.filter_selector .remove_filter_category').show();
          $('.filter_selector .add_filter_category').hide();
          $('.filter_selector .add_filter_category:last').show();
          $('.filter_selector:only-child .remove_filter_category').hide();
        }

        updateFilterUI()

        $('.filter_selector').on('click', '.add_filter_category', function () {

          $('.filter_selector:last').after($('.filter_selector:last').clone(true));

                updateFilterUI();

          $('.filter_selector:last').find('input').val('');
                return false;
            });

        $('.filter_selector .remove_filter_category').on('click', function () {
                $(this).parent().remove();
                updateFilterUI();
                return false;
            });
    });

You can even test it in JSFIDDLE 

Thanks.
```